# Cannot deploy Google Cloud Functions with multiple files

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy some functions script to Firebase Functions. But the following error happens when I try to deploy:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module './helloWorld'
```

I created the project by the `firebase init function` and created two files: `index.ts` and `helloWorld.ts`. I can deploy if I put all code in the same file `index.ts`. But the error happens when I divide the code into both.
I checked that the Typescript is transpiling normally, generating the corresponding files into `lib/` folder.
I looked around the internet, but didn't found a problem like this.

File: index.ts

```
export * from './helloWorld';
```

File: helloWorld.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello World!");
});
```

**Transpiled files:**

File: index.js

```
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__export(require("./helloWorld"));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

File: helloWorld.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello World!");
});
//# sourceMappingURL=helloWorld.js.map
```

I believe that Firebase functions is not deploying the `helloWorld.ts`. Or it is, but not transpiling it to `helloWorld.js`, so that `index.js` cannot find the module `./helloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix that by adding this snippet into `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

But I didn't get why this works.